# Limited Nesting using Nz() in MS Access 2010?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need some help working on Microsoft Access 2010. I've got a situation wherein which I have a master table with all ID's and English Names and seven sub-tables with ID's and Names in another language. The caveat is that the total number of entries from the sum of the seven sub-tables may not match the master table. It may be less.

I'm trying to create Query which displays the ID and **either** the Name in the Foreign Language, or if that doesn't exist then display the English Name.

Initially I wanted to use COALESCE, but then I realized that this is not supported by MS Access.

I've taken two different approaches - the first being an INNER JOIN:

```
M.SID, A.ForeignName
FROM Master M INNER JOIN Class_A A ON M.SID = A.SID

UNION M.SID, A.ForeignName
FROM Master M INNER JOIN Class_B B ON M.SID = B.SID

UNION M.SID, A.ForeignName
FROM Master M INNER JOIN Class_C C ON M.SID = C.SID
...
```

But I cannot capture all records on Master and cannot think of a way to select all records that do not exist on either Class A, B, C, etc. So I decided to try to use Nz() instead:

```
SELECT M.SID,
Nz(
  (SELECT ForeignName FROM Class_A A WHERE M.SID = A.SID), 
  Nz(
    (SELECT ForeignName FROM Class_B B WHERE M.SID = B.SID),
    Nz(
      (SELECT ForeignName FROM Class_C C WHERE M.SID = C.SID),
      EnglishName
      )
   )
)

FROM Master M
```

It works perfectly so long as I stop at Class B, but going beyond causes the error:

> At most one record can be returned by this subquery.

I've also tried to use SWITCH but it doesn't seem to support subqueries.

Comment: If you run those queries individually with the values you're expecting, are any of the queries returning more than one value? `Nz` will only work if the returned `ForeignName` returns just a single row or NULL.

Comment: Can't you just use a nested `IIF` with `IsNull`? Like @AshwinNair said, you either have a duplicate value in Table C, or Nz takes the "C" subselect and adds it to "B".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you have multiple rows with the same SID in either `Class_A`, `Class_B` or `Class_C`. Think of a situation where for a particular `SID` in `Master`, `Class_A` and `Class_B` have no records and `Class_C` has 2 records. In this case, how will MS Access decide which of the `ForeignName`s for these two records to use.

Run the following query:

```
select M.SID, count(A.SID)
from Master M inner join Class_A A on M.SID=A.SID
group by M.SID having count(A.SID)>1
```

Then do the same replacing `Class_A` in the above query with `Class_B` and then `Class_C`. If any of the three queries return something, it's pointing to the SIDs in any of these 3 tables having multiple records with the same `SID`. Your original query won't work until you delete all but one of the offending rows.

Also, I'd stick to using joins as follows to make the query more efficient and readable:

```
SELECT M.SID,
Nz(A.ForeignName, 
   Nz( B.ForeignName, 
      Nz(C.ForeignName, EnglishName)
   )
)
FROM (((Master M left outer join Class_A A on M.SID=A.SID )
left outer join Class_B B on M.SID=B.SID )
left outer join Class_C C on M.SID=C.SID )
```

Left outer joins allow for records in the left table which don't have corresponding records in the right table.

Comment: I finally found the duplicate entries thanks to your query! Initially I thought there weren't any because I set the "SID" field to be the primary key during import but it seems I screwed up at that stage. I'm just wondering though if the LEFT OUTER JOIN is necessary, instead of just using "FROM MASTER" since wouldn't Nz already cover that?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You'll need the from irrespective of the query. If you use an inner join instead of a left outer join,  the query will only return rows common to master and class_a. Also your requirement of also getting back rows present only in master and none of the other tables won't be met